# uiscrollview problem

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiscrollview

I have a view over which i take a scroll view in which i make a small draggable image . now i want to set the image in content view of the scroll view ...how can i 
plz help

Comment: do you have a UIImageView, more Code plz

Answer (score 0):

```
[scrollView addSubview:yourImageview];
```

should add the image view to your scrollview. Make the `contentSize` of the scrollView according to your needs(`yourImage.size` should do it I guess).

Answer (score 0):

```
scrollView.contentSize = imageview.size;
[scrollView addSubView:imageView]
```